# Power BI RS - how can do basic auth?

Tags: authentication, powerbi

I need your help, i want to implement basic auth with Power BI RS in web portal but don't work i got a error message :

**Non-Windows user credentials were provided for a non-http connection to Analysis Services. The Microsoft SQL Server Analysis Services data extension requires integrated Windows security, except when connecting through http or https.**

Do you have any idea ?

Thank you !

Comment: The error seems pretty clear. Are you trying to initiate a non-http connection? Could you share your code and a fuller description of your use case?

Comment: Hi Greggy, thanks for your response i have implement dynamic security in my cube solution and i want to give access to external users (users not in my AD) to the reports in Power BI RS portail.